# Add custom CSS to shortcodes

Tags: wordpress

I'm developing a wordpress plugin. This plugin will use shortcodes to display larges chunks of HTML that are styled with Bootstrap 3. However, I cannot depend on whether or not the theme has bootstrap 3 enabled. Is there a way, from my plugin, to ensure that the bootstrap 3 libraries get added to the page?

I've looked through the documentation and nothing seems clear enough. I have a feeling it has to do with `wp_enqueue_script`, but not sure of the hooks I'd need  to use to tie into the CSS/JS on the main page/post pages/theme header, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The summary is, when your plugin is loaded, you should register bootstrap :

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_plugin_register_scripts' );
function my_plugin_register_scripts(){
     wp_register_script('bootstrap','//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js',array('jquery'),'3.3.2',true);
     wp_register_style('bootstrap','//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '3.3.2');
}
```

Then, when your shortcode is called, you enqueue bootstrap :

```
wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap');
wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap');
```

Comment: I think that answers my question ... simply by calling `wp_enqueue_script`/`wp_enqueue_style`, that will put the script/style within the theme page? Should I call the `enqueue` scripts in my shortcode function, or in my plugin init?

Comment: register gets wordpress ready for it, but does not actually push it out to the browser.  When you are certain you need it, you fire the enqueue function which will push it out to the browser.

Comment: yes, but should I call the `wp_enqueue_...` during my function that renders my shortcode, or somewhere else -- for example, the `init` hook.

Comment: for most efficiency, during your function that renders your shortcode.

Comment: But that calls js as well as css in the footer. Any Idea how to get this into the header?

Comment: Set the last argument in `wp_register_script` to false.